# Access DocumentLibrary via OneDrive API or alternative

Tags: ios, sharepoint, office365, onedrive

I have a private group with a site where we have a document library. (I have access to this group/site)
I am currently trying to access the files within this directory.

Document Library:

> https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-is-a-document-library-3b5976dd-65cf-4c9e-bf5a-713c10ca2872

I registered an application in the azure portal and I think, I set all necessary permissions.

```
Microsoft Graph:
Read all groups
Read directory data
Access directory as the signed in user
Read all files that user can access
Read items in all site collections

Office 365 SharePoint Online:
Read user profiles
Read user files
Read items in all site collections
Read managed metadata

Windows Azure Active Directory:
All permissions given
```

I am able to get a token via OAuth authentication, but:

Accessing

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/

Tells me

> InvalidAuthenticationToken

Accessing

> https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/_api/v1.0/

Is working, but I did not find a way to access the document library from there

In the end, I want to access (List&Read) the files in an iOS application. It would be great, to use the onedrive-sdk for this, as the office365-sdk seems broken for Swift4 at the moment.

I may have left out some information, in that case just ask for them